# Shell script problems with "if [ -d ${directory} ]"

Tags: bash, shell

I want to do something like the following loop to find all the "*e-0[1-9]" directories in a path (1e-04,3e-07 and so on..). If such a directory is found, I want some commands to be executed. My problem is the if condition, which gives me different errors using **sh** or **bash**. The error I get for **sh** is "[: unexpected sequence" and for **bash** is "[: too many arguments". I found this problem in different questions in stackoverflow, but these problems where mostly related to a conversion from "==" to "=" in the if-condition, which is not the case here. The problem part looks like this:

```
for i in `seq 1 9`;
do
    directory=*e-0$i
    // directory="*e-0"+$i    // also tried things like that
    if [ -d ${directory} ]    // THIS is the line stated in the error
    then
        echo $directory
    fi
done
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quote! `if [ -d "${directory}" ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes):

```
if [ -d "$directory" ]
```

Or a **simpler approach** to the whole loop:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for directory in *e-0[1-9]/
```

This doesn't need to check if there's a match, because the loop body will only be run for the matching paths. The trailing slash ensures that it only matches directories

Comment: Nice idea for the loop but the check should still remain, unless you have enabled nullglob `shopt -s nullglob`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The for loop gets the work done! @ Tom Fenech: And yes, I will leave the check in there, which takes care if nothing is found.